# Calculation of Expected Shortfall using IMA Approach ( FRTB)

Tags: time-series, risk-models, liquidity, expected-shortfall

I am trying to calculate the Expected shortfall of a FX portfolio through IMA Approach of FRTB in excel . I have used several combinations in excel to get the liquidity horizons and then calculate the ES, but somehow it is not showing the correct result.

Can someone please share the working excel of calculation of the Expected Shortfall via IMA Approach for any of the portfolio? Any help and suggestion will be much appreciated .

Thanks,
Manish